# Display Child's value in Parent's view; has_one belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, rails-activerecord

I am trying to display a column value of a child in a parent's view file.
The app throws no error but it always returns nil value for some reason and never displays the value.

In my app, Resume has_one Extra.

Here are my codes.

**Resume View (Show.html.erb)**

```
<!--This line shows nothing. Returns nil all the time even though the cell is not empty -->
<% @resume.extra.interests %>
```

**Associations**

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one   :extra
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :extra
end

class Webconnection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resume
end
```

**Resume Controller**

```
class ResumesController < ApplicationController
def show
  @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @title = "Create a new resume"
  @resume = Resume.new
  experience = @resume.experiences.build
  education = @resume.educations.build
  extra = @resume.build_extra
  webconnection = @resume.build_webconnection
end

def create
  @resume = Resume.new(params[:resume])     
  if @resume.save
    #UserMailer.created_resume_email(@user).deliver
    redirect_to @resume
  else
    @title = "Create a new resume"
    render :action => "new"
  end
end
end
```

**Migration file for Webconnections**

```
class CreateExtras < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table  :extras do |t|
      t.text      :interests
      t.text      :recommendations
      t.text      :awards
      t.text      :activities
      t.integer   :resume_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't the first snippet supposed to have an `=` sign like this: `<%= @resume.extra.interests %> `  ?   That's probably not your issue but just so we're clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
<% @resume.extra.interests %>
```

by

```
<%= @resume.extra.interests %>
```

`<% foo %>` evaluates foo but does not print a thing.

`<%= foo %>` evaluates and prints foo

Comment: BOOM! Thank you so much. Can't believe I missed that.